# Substitution system

Tags: algorithm, text

I am currently developing an advanced text editor with some features.

One of the features is a substitution system. It will help user to replace strings quickly.
 It has a following format:

```
((a x) | x) (d e)
```

We can divide the string into two parts: left `((a x) | x)`  and right `(d e)`. If there is a letter (`x`, in current case) after a `|`, then we then can perform a substitute action - replace all `x` in the left side with a string on the right side.
So after the action we will receive `(a (d e))`.

Of course, these parenthesized expressions might be nested : `((a | a) (d x | d)) (e f | f)` -> `((e f | f) x)` -> `(e x)`.

Unfortunately, the reductions may continue infinitely: `(a a | a) (a a | a)`.
I need to show a warning if user would write a string for which there is no way to reduce it into a form without reductions.
Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations, you have just invented the [λ-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) (pronounced "Lambda-calculus")

#### Why this problem is hard

Let's use the original notation for this, since it was already invented by Church in the 1930s:

`((λx.f) u)` is the rewriting of `f` where all `x`'s have been replaced by `u`'s.
Note that this is equivalent to you notation `(f | x) u`, where `f` is a string that can contain `x`'s. It's a mathematical tool introduced to understand what functions are "computable", i.e. can be given to a computer with an adequate program, so that for all input, the computer will run its program and output the correct answer. *Spoiler*: computable functions are exactly the functions that can be written as λ-terms (i.e. rewritings in your settings).

Sometimes λ-terms can be simplified, as you have noted yourself. For instance

`(λx.yx)((λu.uu)(λz.z)i)` -> `(λx.yx)((λz.z)(λz.z)i)` -> `(λx.yx)((λz.z)i)` -> `(λx.yx)i` -> `yi`

Sometimes the sequence of simplifications (also called "evaluation", or "beta-reduction") is infinite. One very famous is the Omega operator `(λx.xx)(λx.xx)` (rings a bell?).

Ideally, we would like to restrict the λ-calculus so that all terms are "simplifiable" to a final usable form in a finite number of steps. This property is called "normalization". The actual thing we want however is one step further : we want that all sequences of simplifications end up in a finite number of steps in the final form, so that when faced with multiple choices, you can choose either and not get stuck in an infinite loop because of a bad choice. This is called "strong normalization".

Here's the issue : the λ-calculus is not strongly normalizing. This property is simply not true. There are terms that do not end up in a final - "normal" - form.
You have found one yourself.

#### How this problem has been solved theoretically

The key to gaining the strong normalization property was to rule out λ-terms which did not satisfy this property (print a warning and spit an error in your case) so that we only consider strongly normalizing λ-terms. This "ruling out" was put in place via a typing system : λ-terms that have a valid type are strongly normalizing, and λ-terms that are not strongly normalizing cannot have a valid type. Awesome, now we know which ones should give errors ! Let's check that with simple cases.

From the way you are able to phrase your problem in a very clear way, I'm assuming you already have experience with programming and static type systems, but I can modify this answer if you'd rather have a full explanation. I'll be using Caml-like notation for types so `s` is a string, `s -> s` is a function that to a string associates a string, and `s -> (s -> s)` is a function that to a string associates a function from string to string, etc. I denote `x : t` when variable `x` has type `t`.

`λx.ax : s -> s` provided `a : s -> s`

`(λx.yx)((λu.uu)(λz.z)i) : s` provided `y : s -> s, i : s` as we have seen by the reductions above

`λx.x : s -> s`. But watch out, `λx.x : (s -> s) -> (s -> s)` is also true. Deciding the type is hard

#### How you may solve this problem programatically

You problem is slightly easier, because you are only dealing with string replacements, so you know that the base type of everything is a string, and you can try to "type you way up" until you are either able to type the whole rewriting (i.e. no errors), or able to prove that the rewriting is not typable (see Omega) and spit an error. Watch out though : just because you are not able to type a rewriting does not mean that it cannot be typed !

In your example `(λx.ax)(de)`, you know the actual values for `a`, `d` and `e` so you may have for instance `a : s -> s`, `d : s -> s`, `e : s`, hence `de : s` and  `λx.ax : s -> s` so the whole thing has type `s` and you're good to go. You can probably write a compiler that will try to type the rewriting and figure out if it's typable or not based on a set of cleverly-crafted decision rules for the specific use that you want. You can even decide that if the compiler fails to type a rewriting, then it is rejected (even when it's valid) because cases so intricate that they will fail though being correct should never happen in a reasonable editor text substitution scenario.

#### Do you want to solve this programatically ?

No. I mean it. You really don't want to.

Remember, λ-terms describe all computable functions.
If you were to really implement a fully correct warning generator as you seem to intend to, this means that one could encode any program as a string substitution in you editor, so your editor is essentially a programming language on its own, which is typically not what you want your editor to be.

I mean, writing a full program that queries the webcam, analyzes the image, guesses who is typing, and loads an ad based on Google's suggestion when opening a file, all as a cleverly-written text substitution command, really ? Is that what you're trying to achieve ?

PS: If this is indeed what you're trying to achieve, have a look at Lisp and Haskell, their syntax should look somewhat... familiar to what you've seen here.
And good luck with your editor !